# Is it possible to set column value as a wildcard? MySQL

Tags: mysql

This is a super strange question, and it usefulness it's probably limited to my problem; I'm going to explain what I'm asking and why I need it.

My problem:

I have a table, let's say with 2 columns, serve the next table as example:

```
id|value
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   A
5   A
```

Now, If I do a "SELECT id WHERE value = 'A', I would get 3 results, 1, 4, 5. If I do a "SELECT id WHERE value = 'B', I would get 1 result, 2. And so on, if there were more entries, I would get the corresponding numbers of rows as my result according the value I'm looking in my query. It's all good.

But now, here comes my problem. Let's say I want to get every row for every query, but with the next restriction:

**Do not modify the queries**.

If I do "SELECT id WHERE value = 'A'", I would get every id, if I do "SELECT id WHERE value = 'B'", I would get every id, and so on.

"But if I can't modify my query, then what can I do?" You may ask, well, you can modify the table, like changing the value of the column 'value' to a value that would match every value, that's a wildcard, hence the title of the question, but I'm pretty sure if I update all 'value' values to '%', it doesn't work (I tried knowing this wouldn't work, but still, I couldn't lose anything trying).

So, you can do whatever you want, the only restriction is to not modify the queries.

I know this is kind of the inverse of how databases and tables should work, but this is a problem I've been presented with, maybe this is impossible, but maybe it's not.

**Edit:**

I know this makes little to no sense at all, but I'm asking this as a kind of challenge, appealing to the creatives minds out there. Don't worry about vulnerabilities or anything else, just ask yourselves: "How would I do it?"

Comment: Not without editing the queries. They'd have to be of the form `WHERE 'B' LIKE value` for changing values to `%` to even have a chance of working.

Comment: My guess is no, though I'd be terribly curious of someone has a really clever way of accomplishing this.  ("Clever" as in "this is so horrible and nobody should ever do this" most likely.)  Databases are really good at querying data, the power is all in the query.  If you "can't modify the query" then you have an entirely different problem that someone is trying to avoid with this potential hack.  Solve the problem, don't bury it under another problem.

Comment: The question does not make sense to me. Please state what your desired output would be, and what are the queries that you don't want modified.

Comment: "Please listen carefully" ... atta way to tame your audience

Comment: @Amadan: The desired output is basically to trick the database into ignoring the `WHERE` clause.  To *always* output all rows regardless of the `WHERE` given in the query.  Which I guess is *possible* if one wants to modify the MySQL source code and compile a custom version.  That would pretty much be the definition of overkill...

Comment: Yeah, not without modifying the query. The easiest that I can see is sticking `OR 1` at the end.

Comment: @Amadan: If the code that can't be modified is SQL-injectable then you might be onto something there :)

Comment: The *mysql* command is open source - you can edit it and change its behavior... Are you trying to hack something??

Comment: @David there is no need to modify mysql's source code. All you need to do is to write your custom table engine, which would return all rows from a table regardless of the where criteria. Of course, this would still be an overkill.

Comment: I know all of this everyone, and thanks for commenting and not down voting (...), and thanks @David for at least understanding the purpouse of the question, and I will correct the problem, I just got super curious, since the easiest solution would be a wildcard in the column value, this doesn't mean that this is what should be done though and it's not what I will do, but again, I'm just so curious if this can be accomplished.

Comment: @Shadow mind elaborating on that? Guide me a bit please?

Comment: @Lauro182 You said you'd explain why you need this, but didn't. You're asking what sounds like the classic XY problem. You're asking to solve X (wildcard queries) but you really need to solve Y (how do I change these apparently unchangeable queries)? Why don't you ask about Y instead?

Comment: @Lauro182 mysql has an extendible table engine model. You can create your table engine and then install it as a plug-in on your mysql server. This way the core mysql functionality is unchanged. Mysql even created the opposite of what you want: a table engine that does not return anything when you query it and swallows all data you send to it. Its name is befitting: blackhole. For further reading: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pluggable-storage-overview.html

Comment: @Schwern Sorry if I forgot to explay why I needed this, I just got carried away trying to figure out a solution myself. The reason for this question is that the project is super big, and the queries are armed in several different ways, some concatenate string, some use query builders, etc, and I just can't search for the query, so I thought of this solution, but yeah, I'm looking for every query and fixing the problem like it should be done. But still, it would be great if someone could think of some easy solution like it would be the wildcard in the column value.

Comment: @Shadow thanks for answer man, I've read it and I had no idea this existed, I won't be implementing this though, but it's good to know mysql have this, it can be very handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I present any solutions, let me make it clear that ***you are solving the wrong problem***. You should be figuring out how to change your queries; that restriction will continue to generate more problems. Any solution to this problem will be so complex it will generate more problems.

Hopefully this really is just an intellectual exercise.

I'm also going to only give sketches on how to do this, because this is just an intellectual exercise RIGHT?!

---

The first, and most comprehensive solution is to "just" change the source code of your MySQL database to respond to the queries however you like.  It's an Open Source database. Download the source code, change it, recompile, and install.

The downside to this solution (assuming you can make it work) is it effects every connection to the database and has to be repeated every time you want to upgrade MySQL.

---

***Assuming this is restricted to one table, and that the set of WHERE clauses is fixed***, you can duplicate every row in that table to have every value which might be queried.  For example, if you have id's 1 and 2 and value is only ever A, B or C, you'd make a table like this:

```
id|value
1  A
1  B
1  C
2  A
2  B
2  C
```

---

Then there are various man-in-the-middle attacks you can do to strip off the WHERE clause.  If it's a fixed set of programs which are the problem you could alter the database API library they use.  In Perl this would be the DBI library.  In PHP this would be mysqli or PDO.  And so on.

A more comprehensive solution would be to replace the MySQL server's socket (both the TCP and Unix socket) with your own little server.  This would read and parse the MySQL network protocol (you may be able to extract the code to do this from the MySQL source), alter the query to strip the WHERE clause, and send it on to the real MySQL server.

---

These are all terrible solutions that are horribly difficult to implement correctly. Even if you got them working 100%, you're left with a system that does strange things to database queries which is likely to cause further problems down the road.

***One of the most creative solutions to a problem is to realize you're solving the wrong problem***.

I encourage you to post the circumstances that lead to this question, as another question, because that is the real problem.  Also the management failures which lead to it will be a nice train wreck to watch.

Comment: Maybe asker not from this universe. I agree with the response from the Schwern

Comment: Again, there is no need to modify mysql's source code, just create your own table engine and plug it in. Yeah, still an overkill.

Comment: @Shadow "Just" create your own table engine. :) Probably one that alters the query and hands it off to InnoDB. It's very clever.

Comment: @Schwern Thanks for your answer man, this in indeed a merely intellectual exercise, your solutions indeed create a lot more problems and are a bit hard to implement, I've read Shadow's link and this solution  might be more doable. I'll wait to see if there are any other answers, if not, I'll mark this as the answer, since shadow didn't post it as answer.

Comment: @Lauro182 I'm not going to post it as an answer because 1) it is still an overkill and may create more problems on the long run 2) stricktly speaking it is not an answer to your question, since you would still chop off the where part of the query. Unless you want to create an sql parser from scratch.